# Image of linear functional on a product of vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\phi:C^\infty(S^1)\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous linear functional. Let $ v_1,v_2\in C^\infty(S^1)$ non constant and denote $a_i=\phi(v_i)$. Can one express (using possibly $a_i$), $\phi(v_1v_2)$?

Comment: What do you mean by *express*? Can you express $\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})g(e^{it})dt$?

Comment: @Jochen that's essentially what I'm asking: Reisz theorem tells you that $\phi(y)=\langle y,x\rangle$. Can you find *explicitly* a function $T:C^\infty(S^1)\times C^\infty(S^1)\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\langle y_1y_2,x\rangle=T(y_1,y_2)\langle y_1,x\rangle\cdot \langle y_2,x\rangle$?

Comment: If you meant continuous linear functional then $\phi$ is a $1$-periodic tempered distribution, it has a Fourier series, which means $\langle \phi,v \rangle = \sum_n \hat{\phi}(n) \hat{v}(n)$ where $\hat{\phi}(n) =\langle \phi,e^{2i \pi nx} \rangle$ and $\hat{v}(n) = \int_0^1 v(x) e^{-2i \pi nx}dx$. Also in the sense of distributions $\phi = \sum_n \hat{\phi}(n) e^{2i \pi nx}$.

Comment: @reuns that's true. How does it help to show you can(not) find such $T$?

Comment: You won't get anything more concrete than the Fourier series I wrote. Usually Riesz is for Hilbert spaces, and what you wrote with your $T$ doesn't make sense (try with $\langle y_1,x \rangle = 0$)

Comment: @reuns If I assume that $\langle y_i,x\rangle\neq 0$, does $T$ make sense?

Comment: No. What makes sense is $\langle \phi, y_1 y_2 \rangle = T(y_1,y_2)$ which is indeed a definition of $T$.